# How to alter the script so it suits the dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to ask about how to code the right code for I have a dropdown list of universities name and if there's no user's university name, they can click on the other button and a form or box appear so they can input their university name?

Below is my code; I try to use this javascripts but the box appear right besides the dropdown list
Here is the JS

```js
function yesnoCheck1() {
  if (document.getElementById('yesCheck1').checked) {
    document.getElementById('ifYes1').style.display = 'block';
  } else document.getElementById('ifYes1').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<div class="form=group">
  <label>University</label><br>

  <select name="university" class="form-control">

    <option value="">--select one--</option>
    <option disabled>
      <hr>
    </option>
    <option value="" style="font-weight:bold"><label>GENERAL UNIVERSITY</label> <br></option>
    <option disabled>
      <hr>
    </option>

    <option value="Universiti Kebangsaan Malaysia">Universiti Kebangsaan Malaysia </option>
    <option value="Universiti Malaya"> Universiti of Malaya</option>
    <option value="Univeristy of Malaysia Kelantan">University of Malaysia Kelantan </option>
    <option value="University of Malaysia Pahang">University of Malaysia Pahang </option>
    <option value="University of Malaysia Perlis">University of Malaysia Perlis</option>
    <option value="University of Malaysia Sarawak">University of Malaysia Sarawak </option>
    <option value="University of Malaysia Sabah">University Malaysia Sabah</option>
    <option value="Universiti Pertahanan Nasional Malaysia">Universiti Pertahanan Nasional Malaysia</option>
    <option value="Universiti Pendidikan Sultan Idris">Universiti Pendidikan Sultan Idris</option>
    <option value="Universiti Putra Malaysia">Universiti Putra Malaysia</option>
    <option value="Universiti Sains Malaysia">Universiti Sains Malaysia</option>
    <option value="Universiti Sains Islam Malaysia">Universiti Sains Islam Malaysia </option>
    <option value="Universiti Islam Antarabangsa Malaysia"> Universiti Islam Antarabangsa Malaysia</option>
    <option value="Universiti Sultan Zainal Abidin"> Universiti Sultan Zainal Abidin</option>
    <option value="Universiti Teknologi Malaysia">Universiti Teknologi Malaysia</option>
    <option value="University of Malaysia Terengganu">Universiti of Malaysia Terengganu</option>
    <option value="Universitu Tun Hussein Onn Malaysia">Universiti Tun Hussein Onn Malaysia</option>
    <option value="University Teknikal Malaysia Melaka">Universiti Teknikal Malaysia Melaka</option>
    <option value="Universiti Teknologi Malaysia">Universiti Teknologi Malaysia</option>
    <option value="Universiti Teknologi MARA">Universiti Teknologi MARA</option>
    <option value="Univesiti Utara Malaysia">Universiti Utara Malaysia</option>

    <option disabled>
      <hr>
    </option>
    <option value="" style="font-weight:bold">PRIVATE UNIVERSITY</label>
      </br>
    </option>
    <option disabled>
      <hr>
    </option>

    <option value="Al-Bukhary International University">Al-Bukhary International University</option>
    <option value="AIMST University"> AIMST University</option>
    <option value="Al-Madinah International University"> Al-Madinah International University</option>
    <option value="International Medical University"> International Medical University</option>
    <option value="INTI International University"> INTI International University</option>
    <option value="Limkokwing University of Creative Technology">Lilmkokwing University of Creative Technology</option>
    <option value="Malaysia University of Science and Technology">Malaysia University of Science and Technology</option>
    <option value="Management and Science University">Management and Science University</option>
    <option value="Multimedia University">Multimedia University</option>
    <option value="Open University Malaysia"> Open University Malaysia</option>
    <option value="Taylor's University"> Taylor's University</option>
    <option value="Universiti Teknologi Petronas Malaysia"> Universiti Teknolgi Petronas Malaysia</option>
    <option value="Universiti Tenaga Nasional"> Universiti Tenaga Nasional</option>
    <option value="Universiti Tun Abdul Razak">Universiti Tun Abdul Razak</option>
    <option value="Universiti Tunku Abdul Rahman"> Universiti Tunku Abdul Rahman</option>
    <option value="Universiti Kuala Lumpur">Univiersiti Kuala Lumpur</option>
    <option value="Universiti Industri Selangor">Universiti Industri Selangor</option>
    <option value="Universiti Sunway">Universiti Sunway</option>
    <option value="Wawasan Open University">Wawasan Open University</option>
    <option value="UCSI University"> UCSI University</option>

    <option disabled>
      <hr>
    </option>
    <option value="" style="font-weight:bold">OVERSEAS UNIVERSITY MALAYSIA'S CAMPUS</label>
      </br>
    </option>
    <option disabled>
      <hr>
    </option>

    <option value="Curtin Technology University">Curtin Technology University </option>
    <option value="Monash Malaysia University ">Monash Malaysia University</option>
    <option value="Swinburne Technology University">Swinburne Technology University</option>
    <option value="Nottingham University of Malaysia"> Nottingham University of Malaysia</option>
    <option value="Medical University of Newcastle, Malaysia"> Medical University of Newcastle, Malaysia</option>

    <option disabled>
      <hr>
    </option>
    <option value='' for="yesCheck1">Others..</option>
    <input type="radio1" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck1();" name="yesno1" id="yesCheck">
  </select>
</div>

<div id="ifYes1" style="display:none">

  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="uname" name="uname" placeholder="Please write your Universirty"></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is how my form looks for now the form appears just right beside my dropwdown box. I really don't know how to alter it anymore. Every suggestions and help is very much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Your HTML in highly invalid. Why not just react to the others select option? There is no HTML object with type="radio1"

Comment: you have no element with `id = 'yesCheck1'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML in highly invalid.

- There is no HTML object with type="radio1",
- no object called yesCheck1 and you have nothing on the page that can be 
  "checked"
- Use OPTGROUP for the labels since `<hr/>` is not a valid option text
- You cannot have input fields nor `<br>` inside selects

Why not just react to the others select option?

```js
document.querySelector("[name=university]").onchange = function() {
  document.getElementById("ifYes1").style.display = this.value == "others" ? "block" : "none"; // or use class and classList
}

// jQuery very similar

// $("[name=university]").on("change",function() {
//   $("#ifYes1").toggle(this.value=="others);
// });
```

```css
.bold { font-weight:bold }
```

```html
<div class="form=group">
  <label>University</label><br>

  <select name="university" class="form-control">

    <option value="">--select one--</option>
    <option value="" disabled></option>
    <optgroup label="GENERAL UNIVERSITY">
      <option value="Universiti Kebangsaan Malaysia">Universiti Kebangsaan Malaysia </option>
      <option value="Universiti Malaya"> Universiti of Malaya</option>
      <option value="Univeristy of Malaysia Kelantan">University of Malaysia Kelantan </option>
      <option value="University of Malaysia Pahang">University of Malaysia Pahang </option>
      <option value="University of Malaysia Perlis">University of Malaysia Perlis</option>
      <option value="University of Malaysia Sarawak">University of Malaysia Sarawak </option>
      <option value="University of Malaysia Sabah">University Malaysia Sabah</option>
      <option value="Universiti Pertahanan Nasional Malaysia">Universiti Pertahanan Nasional Malaysia</option>
      <option value="Universiti Pendidikan Sultan Idris">Universiti Pendidikan Sultan Idris</option>
      <option value="Universiti Putra Malaysia">Universiti Putra Malaysia</option>
      <option value="Universiti Sains Malaysia">Universiti Sains Malaysia</option>
      <option value="Universiti Sains Islam Malaysia">Universiti Sains Islam Malaysia </option>
      <option value="Universiti Islam Antarabangsa Malaysia"> Universiti Islam Antarabangsa Malaysia</option>
      <option value="Universiti Sultan Zainal Abidin"> Universiti Sultan Zainal Abidin</option>
      <option value="Universiti Teknologi Malaysia">Universiti Teknologi Malaysia</option>
      <option value="University of Malaysia Terengganu">Universiti of Malaysia Terengganu</option>
      <option value="Universitu Tun Hussein Onn Malaysia">Universiti Tun Hussein Onn Malaysia</option>
      <option value="University Teknikal Malaysia Melaka">Universiti Teknikal Malaysia Melaka</option>
      <option value="Universiti Teknologi Malaysia">Universiti Teknologi Malaysia</option>
      <option value="Universiti Teknologi MARA">Universiti Teknologi MARA</option>
      <option value="Univesiti Utara Malaysia">Universiti Utara Malaysia</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option value="" disabled></option>

    <optgroup label="PRIVATE UNIVERSITY">
      <option value="Al-Bukhary International University">Al-Bukhary International University</option>
      <option value="AIMST University"> AIMST University</option>
      <option value="Al-Madinah International University"> Al-Madinah International University</option>
      <option value="International Medical University"> International Medical University</option>
      <option value="INTI International University"> INTI International University</option>
      <option value="Limkokwing University of Creative Technology">Lilmkokwing University of Creative Technology</option>
      <option value="Malaysia University of Science and Technology">Malaysia University of Science and Technology</option>
      <option value="Management and Science University">Management and Science University</option>
      <option value="Multimedia University">Multimedia University</option>
      <option value="Open University Malaysia"> Open University Malaysia</option>
      <option value="Taylor's University"> Taylor's University</option>
      <option value="Universiti Teknologi Petronas Malaysia"> Universiti Teknolgi Petronas Malaysia</option>
      <option value="Universiti Tenaga Nasional"> Universiti Tenaga Nasional</option>
      <option value="Universiti Tun Abdul Razak">Universiti Tun Abdul Razak</option>
      <option value="Universiti Tunku Abdul Rahman"> Universiti Tunku Abdul Rahman</option>
      <option value="Universiti Kuala Lumpur">Univiersiti Kuala Lumpur</option>
      <option value="Universiti Industri Selangor">Universiti Industri Selangor</option>
      <option value="Universiti Sunway">Universiti Sunway</option>
      <option value="Wawasan Open University">Wawasan Open University</option>
      <option value="UCSI University"> UCSI University</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option value="" disabled></option>

    <optgroup label="OVERSEAS UNIVERSITY MALAYSIA'S CAMPUS">
      <option value="Curtin Technology University">Curtin Technology University </option>
      <option value="Monash Malaysia University ">Monash Malaysia University</option>
      <option value="Swinburne Technology University">Swinburne Technology University</option>
      <option value="Nottingham University of Malaysia"> Nottingham University of Malaysia</option>
      <option value="Medical University of Newcastle, Malaysia"> Medical University of Newcastle, Malaysia</option>
    </optgroup>
    <option value="" disabled></option>
    <option value='others' class="bold">Others…</option>
  </select>
</div><br/>

<div id="ifYes1" style="display:none">

  <div class="form-group">
    <input class="form-control" id="uname" name="uname" placeholder="Please write your Universirty" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would downvoters explain why they downvoted? It's too mainstream, probably

Comment: @JeremyThille Because NO ONE is learning ANYTHING from an uncommented downvote. and it is disheartening not to be able to defend code - mainstream what?

Comment: oh, thank you. The code work perfectly fine now for me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

- Your HTML markup is **invalid**. You cannot use `<hr>` inside `option`.
- You cannot use `<input>` inside `<select>`
- Don't use inline CSS and Javascript
- `</br>` is invalid markup. Should be `<br>` or eventually `<br/>`
- `input` is a **Void** element and does not closes with `</input>`
- If `value` matches the `<option>` **text**, it can be excluded.
- You should use `<optgroup>` for grouping.
- Create a `.none` class style with `display: none;` and set it to your `#uni_other` input wrapper element.
- Toggle that `none` class on select change event:

```js
var uni_select = document.querySelector("[name='university']");
var uni_other = document.getElementById("uni_other")

uni_select.addEventListener("change", function() {
  uni_other.classList.toggle("none", this.value !== "uni_other")
});
```

```css
.none {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form=group">
  <label>University</label><br>

  <select name="university" class="form-control">

    <option value="">--select one--</option>

    <optgroup label="GENERAL UNIVERSITY">
      <option>Universiti Kebangsaan Malaysia </option>
      <option>Universiti of Malaya</option>
      <option>University of Malaysia Kelantan </option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="PRIVATE UNIVERSITY">
      <option>Al-Bukhary International University</option>
      <option>AIMST University</option>
      <option>Al-Madinah International University</option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="OVERSEAS UNIVERSITY MALAYSIA'S CAMPUS">
      <option>Al-Bukhary International University</option>
      <option>AIMST University</option>
      <option>Al-Madinah International University</option>
    </optgroup>

    <option value='uni_other'>Other&hellip;</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group none" id="uni_other">
  <input class="form-control" name="uname" placeholder="Please write your Universirty">
</div>
```

Comment: this is my first time knowing about optgroup. Thank you very much! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Attach a "change" event to your `<select>` element
2. On change, read the selected value
3. Display or hide the input field based on the value.

```js
const ifYes1 = document.getElementById("ifYes1")

const selectChanged = event => {

 let value = event.target.value;
 
 ifYes1.style.display = value==="other" ? "block" : "none";
 
 /* Same thing as :
   if(value==="other"){
      ifYes1.style.display = "block";
   } else {
      ifYes1.style.display = "none";
   }
 */ 
}
```

```css
#ifYes1{
    display : none;
    margin-top : 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form=group">
  <label>University</label><br>

  <select onchange="selectChanged(event)">
    <option value="swinburne">Swinburne Technology University</option>
    <option value="nottingham">Nottingham University of Malaysia</option>
    <option value="newcastle">Medical University of Newcastle, Malaysia</option>
    <option disabled></option>
    <option value='other'>Other..</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="ifYes1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="uname" placeholder="Please write your University"/>
  </div>
</div>
```